# How to get default Window TextBox Context Menu in?

Tags: c++, windows, textbox, contextmenu

I develop custom widget set from scratch in windows.This widget set controls (except Form control) doesn't have window handle.

Now, I have show default TextBox Context Menu when user right click over TextBox control but I can't find any solution to get default context menu from windows API.

1- Is there way to get default Context Menu of windows TextBox ?
2- Where can I see some example around windows Context Menus ?

Comment: Question 1 is to broad (the only possible answer to that is really "yes"). Question 2 is off-topic.

Comment: If you want a context menu for your custom windowless control you are going to need to create your own.

Comment: Popup windows has own handle. and controls that need parent handle use form handle as parent, so there is no problem to using context menu

Comment: My form window process all of windows messages like selection , cut , copy , drag and drop and many other things and pass them to active control